# riak - unable to delete keys in a bucket

Tags: riak

I am using riak version 1.4.10 and it is in a ring with two hosts. I am unable to get rid of keys left over from previous operations using simple delete operations on keys. When I list the keys for a bucket, it shows me the old keys, however if I try to retrieve the data associated with a key, no data is found. When I try to delete the key, it still persists. What could be the cause of this? Is there a way to wipe the keys in the bucket so it starts from a clean slate? I don't care about any of the data in riak, but I would rather not have to reinstall everything again.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably seeing the tombstones of the old data.  Since Riak is an eventually consistent data store, it needs to keep track of deletes as if they were ordinary writes, at least for a little while.

If data is present on one node, but not another, how do you tell if it is a PUT that hasnt' propagated yet, or a DELETE?

Riak solves this by using a tombstone.  Whenever you delete something, instead of just wiping the data immediately, Riak replaces the existing value with a special value that it knows means deleted.  This special value contains a vclock that is descended from the previous value, and metadata indicating deleted.  So when it comes time to decide the above question, Riak simply compares the vclock of the value with that of the tombstone.  Whichever descends from the other must be the correct one.

To solve the problem of an ever growing data size that contains mostly tombstones, tombstones are reaped after a time.  The time is set using the delete_mode setting.  After the DELETE is processed, and the tombstone has been written to the primary vnodes, the delete process issues a GET request for the key.  Whenever the GET process encounters a tombstone, and all of the primary vnodes responded with the same tombstone, it schedules the tombstone to be reaped according to the delete_mode setting.

So if you want to actually get rid of the tombstones, check your delete_mode setting to make sure it is not set to 'keep', and issue a get for each one to make sure it is really gone.

Or if you are just wiping the data store to restart your tests, stop Riak, delete all the files under the data_root for the backend you are using, and restart.